# Mongoose: filter option in a aggregation query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate

I'm having problems filtering out data in a query. My original query works, but I get 0 results if I add a match statement at the end of the pipepline (if Base in code). Base is a field in users.

```
    const aggregationPipeline = [
    { $match: { endDate: { $gte: startDate }, display: true } },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField: "_id", as: "userData" } },
    { $unwind: "$userData" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$userData.crewCode",
            base: { $first: "$userData.base" },
            rank: { $first: "$userData.rank" },
            rosters: { $push: "$rawData" }
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 1, base: 1, rank: 1, rosters: 1 } },
    { $sort: { rank: 1, _id: 1 } }
];

if (base) {
    aggregationPipeline.push({ $match: { "userData.base": { $eq: base } } });
}

const userSchedules = await Schedule.aggregate(aggregationPipeline).exec();
```

Comment: Without a sample document it's a bit like shooting in the dark. However, you are pushing to the end of the aggregation but clearly you cannot do a `$match` on `userData.base` at the end because by then you have done a `$group` and then afterwards you only `$project` 4 fields and none of them is `userData` so `userData` does not exist at those points. You need to figure out at which point is going to be best. Perhaps `aggregationPipeline.splice(2, 0, { $match: { "userData.base": { $eq: base } } })`

Comment: Agree with @jQueeny. You can use tools like Compass to build your aggregations. They will often help you understand what the intermediate objects look like at different stages in the pipeline which seems to be the root of the problem here

Answer (score 1):

As I read and understand your problem, I think this solution should work for you:

You push a match condition at last is `{ $match: { "userData.base": { $eq: base } } }` but, after the group and project stage, you don't have any access for `userData`, so your condition should be like `{ $match: { "base": { $eq: base } } }`.

```
 const aggregationPipeline = [
    { $match: { endDate: { $gte: startDate }, display: true } },
    { $lookup: { from: "users", localField: "user", foreignField: "_id", as: "userData" } },
    { $unwind: "$userData" },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$userData.crewCode",
            base: { $first: "$userData.base" },
            rank: { $first: "$userData.rank" },
            rosters: { $push: "$rawData" }
        }
    },
    { $project: { _id: 1, base: 1, rank: 1, rosters: 1 } },
    { $sort: { rank: 1, _id: 1 } }
];

if (base) {
    aggregationPipeline.push({ $match: { "base": { $eq: base } } });
}

const userSchedules = await Schedule.aggregate(aggregationPipeline).exec();
```